# How use Dynamic Named Range of Excel in sql

Tags: delphi

I created in Excel a dynamic named range with name 'sale', on sheet 'Sales':

```
=OFFSET(Sales!$A2,0,0,COUNTA(Sales!$A:$A),8)
```

Then I use TFDConnection and TFDQuery components for connection with it. Driver is ODBC.

I know how to use in SQL a static, non-named range:

```
select * from [Sales$]
select * from [Sales$A1:A100]
```

but if I write SQL for a dynamic named range like

```
select * from [Sales$sale]
```

I get an error that a table with this name isn't found.

How do I correctly write name of **Named Range/Dynamic Named Range** in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: It is not possible.

You can only use user defined static named ranges as table in ODBC query.
The following can't be used:

- dynamic named ranges
- automatically created named ranges (for Tables, print areas)

There is a way to verify if a named range can be used as a SQL table: from Excel choose:

Data->New query->From other sources->From Microsoft Query
Connect to the same ODBC source and you will see list of available tables (or a message that there are no).

It will however not show named ranges with scope set to "Worksheet" on the first attempt and those can still be used. This bug gets fixed when you first return any results from the query back to Excel, and then choose to edit the query.

To get similar results without querying dynamic named range you can use one of the following approaches:

1. If you are not worried about named range location in future you can use:

   `select * from [Sales$A2:H] where A is not null`

The `is not null` condition is only needed if there is some other data below the table in B:H columns. Even without it only an intersection of the range you query and UsedRange will be returned.

2. If the location of the data can change in future, you can define "sale" static named range large enough to make sure it contains all the data (even to the last row of the worksheet), but then you absolutely need the `is not null` condition:

   `select * from sale where A is not null`

If the named range has scope set to "Worksheet", then you need to add the worksheet's name:

`select * from Sales$sale where A is not null`